# Floating Divs in Bootstrap Grid System

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the twitter bootstrap grid system for a responsive website. Most of my markup works just fine, but I've one nasty problem, which makes me mad. I've prepared a JSFiddle to let you see what happens: http://jsfiddle.net/gqb5hbza/

Here is my markup

```
<section>
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
            <div class="item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="adaptive-img" src="http://placehold.it/400x330" />
                </a>

                <div class="item-content">
                    <a href="#"><h4 class="h4 black">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title </h4></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ..........
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I've multiple div boxes which contains an image and a headline. These boxes are rearranged when changing the browser window. But if one of these boxes has a different height (i.e. too long headline which needs two lines), the system breaks and doesn't rearrange correctly - as you can see in the fiddle. The fourth box should be under the first box and not beneath.

Hope that somebody can help me with this problem.

Comment: You could truncate the title using                                                            .item-content h4 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
}

Comment: This happens with all floats in CSS, it's not Bootstrap. Each col-X must be the same exact height at all viewport widths to layout correctly or you use a clearfix after 12 columns with responsive utilities (which doesn't look that great, but it's okay) or use a masonry script.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, if you want to keep your layout as-is (e.g. not explicitly defining each row), the best solution is to keep each col div the same height. You could use Bootstrap's thumbnail/caption classes to make things look a little more tidy, and then adjust the min-height values for the caption using media queries to keep the extra white space to a minimum.

```
<section>
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="adaptive-img" src="http://placehold.it/400x330" />
                </a>

                <div class="caption">
                    <a href="#"><h4 class="h4 black">Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title Title </h4></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
   </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Then add something similar to this css:

```
.caption { min-height: 275px;}

@media(min-width: 400px) {
  .caption { min-height: 100px;}
}
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9u3L6p0q/) with this code. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: This was also my first idea, but you'll have some problem when only a few of them have such a long text. The min-height then will "destroy" the whole layout with big gaps. I'm now using the [Responsive Column Resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) of Bootstrap and I'm really happy with them. I've updated the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gqb5hbza/5/) so all can see the difference.